# Chrome devtools - store custom location

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Chrome comes with a default list of cities to use to set the sensors > location value. But I need a different city and have to type in the values all the time. How can I set 52.37, 4.895 as an extra value.

[image]

Comment: It's hardcoded in the DevTools JS, so I don't think it's possible at the moment https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/devtools/front_end/emulation/SensorsView.js?q=PresetLocations&sq=package:chromium&l=452&dr=C

Comment: Feature request created: https://crbug.com/678062